SortableJS collapse list items on drag
I am using SortableJS to implement drag and drop for a todo app. Sample structure like so:
List 1:
- Item
- Item
- Item

List 2:
- Item a
- Item b
- Item c

To make list drags more effective, I would like to hide the items when I do the drag. This I can manage through CSS (display: none) by hiding on drag start and showing again on drag end. However, when I start the drag, because the items disappear, SortableJS fills-in the empty spaces with lists lower down the order. As you can imagine, this causes everything to be out of place.
I haven't seen anything in SortableJS which will help me with this issue but I wonder if there are some techniques I can employ to make this sort experience better? e.g. on drag, hide everything and show a separate div with only list items and somehow transfer the mouse grab to the list in the new div?
Appreciate any ideas!

replace display: none with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0?

That's a great point. I'm thinking if this serves as a good solution overall. Allows me to move between lists without seeing the items. However, the user still has to move big chunks of the list and I'm trying to see if there's a way to reduce it all down to the list names only.
